# Date.ValueOf error

Tags: apex, validation

I have a validation rule implemented on a Apex class as below. But it doesn't work always. some times even `error=False` it goes to error mode.
IS there something wrong with `Date.valueOf` ??

```
if ( assmt.Assessment_Date__c>= Date.valueOf('2017-01-01') &&
     assmt.Training_Plan_Start_Date__c < date.valueof('2017-01-01')){
  error = true;
  assmt.Assessment_Date__c.addError('Assessor Portals will only accept assessments with a date in 2016. If you wish to submit credit reporting with a 2017 date, please contact your Learning Support Advisor.');
}
```

Comment: valueOf is comparing a string with a date. You should compare variables of the same type.

Comment: Use validation rules for this functionality. And use separate validations.

Comment: Are you sure you want to validate that both conditions are true at the same time? It seems like it should be either/or.

Comment: Yes, I want to validate both conditions

Comment: are assessment_date__c and training_plan_start_date__c always non-null?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use two separate `Validation Rules` for this functionality. Your error message doesn't have anything to do with validation of `Training_Plan_Start_Date__c`, and I can imagine as an end user I would be pretty frustrated with this current implementation.

**Assessment Date**

```
YEAR(Asessment_Date__c) < 2017
```

> Assessor Portals will only accept...

**Training Plan Start Date**

```
Year(Training_Plan_Start_Date__c) >= 2017
```

> Some message related to the field being validated

Comment: I get compile error : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: YEAR(Date).

Comment: @jay These are validation rules, not apex...